# Skip unique constraint bean validation when editing existing entity

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation, unique-constraint

I have a unique field valiation problem. This could apply to any unique field on any object, but in my case right now, I have a user and I want the username to be unique in the database.

A snippet from my User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    @UniqueUsername
    private String username;
}
```

UniqueUsername is a custom constraint annotation as follows:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy =  {UniqueUsernameValidator.class})
public @interface UniqueUsername {

    String message() default "User already exists with this username";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Then UniqueUsernameValidator is a custom constraint validator that simply checks the DB for an existing user with the given username:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class UniqueUsernameValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueUsername, String> {

    @Inject
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean valid = false;
        try {
            userRepo.findByUsername(value);
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            // No result means username not already used
            valid = false
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Now for a new user, the validation works great. The problem I am having is when I edit a user that already exists. When a user is updated, the validation finds the user I am currently editing, returns false and rejects the edit.

Ideally my validator would probably have access to/knowledge of the user object being validated (rather than just the field value) so that I could check whether the duplicate object I found in the database was the same as that being edited. But I cannot find a way of doing that in my validator.

Anyone else come across this problem and come up with an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

What about to use combination of username and generated primary key (ID). Using id for references will be even faster and you will get additional information which can resolve if you are updating or creating new entity.

Your validation will need to be moved to entity level and then you can check whether entity has null id (creating new) or has some id (updating existing).

When creating new then check if no other entity with same name exists.
When updating do the same check but if you found entity with same name make sure that it is not the same entity - using id.

As you wrote this situation is not just about user but about entities in general and this approach can solve also situation with more than one unique fields.

Answer (score -1):

I face the same problem, I skipped the validator for the update action in this way:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    StackTraceElement[] elements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        StackTraceElement element = elements[i];
        if(element.getMethodName().equals("preUpdate")){
            return true;
        }
    }
```